# How to monitor whether a remote process has crashed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, monitoring, remote-server

I have a large number of instances across multiple cloud providers. Each of them is running a single Java program. I want to check that all of these Java programs are running and haven't crashed, and if/when one of them crashes, I want to be alerted about it.

At the moment I have a hacked-together solution that I run from my local computer, which will loop through an array of all the IP addresses, and send a command through SSH to each of them to check `ps -ef` and count the number of Java processes are running. If that number is zero then I will popup something on my screen to alert me.

Is there a better solution? Ideally I could use a Zabbix-style tool to handle it for me but I don't know if anything exists that serves this need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large number of applications running in the cloud then you may like to consider Cloud monitoring tools instead of re-inventing the wheel. I am sure you would like to monitor more than just the process up/down status. There are plenty of cloud monitoring tools, which allow you to monitor both the platform(machines) and the processes. Also, the different types of notifications can be configured depending on the need.

I would suggest that you look into Cloud monitoring solutions such as New Relic/Datadog/Pager Duty/etc. If it is commercially viable then I would highly recommend you to use them.

Comment: Are any of these free & will alert me when a Java process crashes? Datadog looks like it'll cost money.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all of your services write a status metric to CloudWatch Metrics and create an alarm when any do not report a status. [This example](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-custom-metrics/) shows using CloudWatch metrics to report on linux performance counters.